# How to get GTFS text files into an iOS app?

Tags: ios, import, text-files, gtfs

Really general question, but I have a bunch of GTFS text files and I would like to use them in my app.  The end goal is to be able to locate the users current location and match it up with the nearest bus stop via the GTFS stop.txt file. How exactly can I get these text files into my code?

Comment: you may have looked here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/transit-developers/HejCeWWDQ8Y

Answer (score 0):

What I did was create an SQLite3 db out of the tables that interested me and zip that. On first run I unzip the db and it's ready to go from then on.